# Block of text as user input - Using Scanner with Java

Tags: java, input

If I ask for user input with scanner, and they enter for example:

```
I am going to France
and then I am going to Spain
and finally I am going home
```

as a block of text and press enter, how can I create a string that contains those three lines?

Using Scanner.nextline() I can only get the first line.

Comment: How many times do they press enter? They way you have it here it looks like all the text is entered on one line.

Comment: They press enter once, and that was my mistake, it is entered:

I am going to France (new line)

and then I am going to Spain (new line)

and finally I am going home

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will get you close, it will need some tweaking

```
StringBuffer input = new StringBuffer();
while (scanner.hasNextLine())
{
    input.append(scanner.nextline());
}

System.out.println(input.toString());
```

Comment: There is always one next line when reading from standard input. The loop will never end. Some special input must be entered to signal the end of the block (a blank line, a dot, whatever). And StringBuilder should be used instead of StringBuffer.

Comment: Noted, I shall make sure to have something that will end the loop. Thank you!

Comment: @MikeB: but what's the point in recommending to use StringBuffer instead of using StringBuilder, if you know StringBuilder should be preferred to StringBuffer.

Comment: No, in this case, as in 99.999% of the cases, there's no reason to use a StringBuffer instead of a StringBuilder. But I see you also like infinite loops, so it doesn't surprise me that you prefer bad choices over good ones. Using a synchronized class doesn't make code thread-safe magically.

Comment: It has the advantage of not promoting a class that shouldn't be used anymore, because its synchronizedness is useless and makes the code not as efficient as it should be.

Comment: Whenever it is used in a single thread, especially in this case where it is used as a local variable in a single method, and cannot escape, there is no reason to use StringBuffer. StringBuilder really should be preferred in such cases. If it was stored in a field, even if it was not accessed from another thread, one could prefer StringBuffer, guarding against the case where the code might change and it could be used from another thread. But in a case like this, just use StringBuilder.

Comment: Would you teach kids that pigeons should be used to send messages rather than email, just because in this case, reliability and fast arrival is not important?

Comment: And if you want a specific use case, here is one : `java ReadFromSystemIn < fileWithMegaBytesOfText.txt`.

Comment: I would teach them to "Do the simplest thing that can possibly work", because unnecessary complexity in software is a very bad thing. By the way, if you just write `s1 + s2` where s1 and s2 are strings, the code javac emits uses `StringBuilder`. Do you think the compiler writers got it wrong?

Comment: When giving examples, be aware that this example will be reused in other cases, similar, but different. Your crappy code snippet will be reused by people wanting to read lines from standard input, and these people will fail because it has an infinite loop. And it will be used by people reading lines from a big file, and they will suffer an (admittedly small) performance penalty because you recommended the bas default choice.

Comment: If it were in an instance variable, I might agree. But when trivial escape analysis shows no other thread can ever see it, there is no reason for the extra complexity, and the thread-safety of StringBuffer isn't really safe for the same reason that Vector isn't (composite operations, like checking the contents before deciding whether to append a newline, aren't atomic). (String concatenation uses StringBuilder, though not across loops.) You guys should continue this in chat; I'm moving on.

Comment: OK. So your strategy is to always answer with crappy infinite loops and bad practices just to force people to understand why their code sucks. What are you doing here, seriously?

Comment: I understand why StringBuffer is useless. You've been told twice (by David and by me) that, even in multi-threaded code, using a StringBuffer is useless and doesn't magically make the code thread-safe. But yeah, I'm blindly following advices and you understand everything (except loops).

Comment: @JBNizet Using a StringBuilder in this instance is equally useless. Using a StringBuilder doesn't magically make your system performant. Continue to prematurely optimize all you want. I understand loops perfectly. What I wasn't familiar with was how the Scanner works when reading from stdin, it's just not something I have used before. However, I was able to use the knowledge I did have to help the OP. The fact remains, in this particular case there is no advantage to using the StringBuilder over the StringBuffer and there is a disadvantage to doing so.

Comment: Which magical disadvantage did you invent? You don't even seem to understand that the StringBuffer is used as a local variable that is not shared between threads at all, in this particular case. It's not a matter of performance. It's a matter of using the good default choice. The one that the smart engineers designing Java decided to pick to implement a + b, despite Mike B's opinion. And guess what, yes, using a StringBuilder instead of a StringBuffer makes the whole thing more performant, admittedly marginally.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a character to exit the loop, like -1 or other code.

```
    String line = null;

    while(scanner.hasNext()){
        line = scanner.nextLine();

        if(line.equals("-1")) break;

        doStuff(line);
    }
```